# Bootstrapping to estimate the mean of a geometric sample

Tags: r

So I need to run the boot strap method for the geometric mean of the population. The 6 measurements are 1,2,2,4,6,6 and the estimate of the population geometric mean based on this sample is gm= (1*2*2*4*6*6)*(1/6). I need to compute the 95% confidence limit on the population geometric mean.

So far I have:

```
 set.seed(13254)
 gmsample <- c(1,2,2,4,6,6)
 gmsample
 n<- length(gmsample)
 gm.hat <- prod(gmsample) ** (1/6)
 gm.hat

 for(b in 1:B){
    inx.boot<- sample(1:n, replace=TRUE)

 gmboot<- gmsample[idx.boot]
 print(gmboot)

 rboot[b] <- prod(gmboot) ** (1/n)
 print(r.boot)
              }

 boot.sd <- sd(r.boot)
 boot.sd
```

I got this from collecting info from the internet, and I'm extremely new to R so any help would be great.

Comment: So what exactly is your programming question here?

Comment: this program doesn't work and I don't know enough about R to know why

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean precisely? Are you getting an error? Not the result you are expecting? If the latter, what result are you expecting?

Comment: there are a few typos in there. so you should fix those first. then you just need to initialize `B` which is the number of runs I suppose and `r.boot` which is the vector of results, so add `B <- 100; r.boot <- numeric(B)` before the loop

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the boot package instead of rolling your own bootstrapping method. For instance, computing 1000 bootstrap replicates of the geometric mean can be done with:

```
gmsample <- c(1,2,2,4,6,6)
library(boot)
b <- boot(gmsample, function(d, i) prod(d[i])^(1/length(i)), 1000)
```

Now you can use the `boot.ci` method to compute confidence intervals. For instance, if you wanted to use the 95% percentile confidence interval, you could do:

```
boot.ci(b, 0.95, "perc")
# BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
# Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates
# 
# CALL : 
# boot.ci(boot.out = b, conf = 0.95, type = "perc")
# 
# Intervals : 
# Level     Percentile     
# 95%   ( 1.701,  4.670 )  
# Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```

There are many other types of confidence intervals, which you can read about with `?boot.ci`.